# JQuery catch any ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i like to catch any ajax `401 Unauthorised` exception, but do no like to change all my ajax queries. Is there a way to change it for any $.ajax call like (overwrite any `error` handler) ?

Comment: using google will bring you an answer in few seconds: `$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
        401: function(){
            //this will catch any and all access denied errors
        }
    }
});`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you can use the global ajax event handlers [.ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/)

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function( event, jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    if ( jqxhr.status== 401 ) {
        $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
    }
});
```

Comment: Some times `jqxhr` is null, but palaѕн solution worked for me.

Comment: From whatever reason when I use this snippet the staus is always 0. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

You can do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
                alert('HTTP Error 401 Unauthorized.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This will catch error in any of your `ajax` calls.

Comment: it will fail in case if an ajax call had `error` callback specified in the options like `$.ajax({url:'', error: function(){}})`

Answer (score 2):

The `$.ajaxSetup()` function will allow you to specify global options for Ajax calls.  Be careful however as other calls to `ajaxSetup()` will overwrite global options and specified local options to the `ajax()` method will override global settings.

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.ajaxError()` as a global method http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Answer (score 1):

To catch a `401` status code simply add

```
  $.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
      401: function(err){
        console.log('Login Failed.', err.responseJSON);
        // or whatever...
      }
    }
  });
```

to your page somewhere before the AJAX call is fired.